# Pass NSMutableArray Data Between Views

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I am having trouble passing my NSMutableArray data from one view to the other.

My view transition works the following way

Send View -> Recipients View

Recipients View -> Send View

In the recipients view I am grabbing the people I want to send my data to. Once I grab the people using an array, I go back to my send view to send those people that data.

In my send view I have the following NSMutableArray

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *sendTo;
```

I initialize it in viewDidLoad like so:

```
self.sendTo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

In my Recipients View I have the following NSMutableArray

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *recipientsArray;
```

I initialize it in the viewDidLoad like so:

```
self.recipientsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

I also have a back button in this controller which tries to handle the passing of the data in the recipientsArray. Please note this array does have data in it up until the point of the view switch.

```
- (IBAction)back {
   SendView *send = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View"];
   send.sendTo = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.recipients];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Any idea why the array in my Send View is returning nil?

Comment: I doubt you want to create a new SendView when going back.

Comment: What? @vikingosegundo

Comment: I doubt you want to create a new SendView when going back.

Comment: I don't think I do? @vikingosegundo

Comment: what does the verb `instantiate` imply?

Comment: So what should I do to simply transfer the data if I am not making a SendView object?

Comment: actually this has been discussed, discovered and expelling a zillion and one times.

Comment: search for "passing back view controller" or similar

Comment: It might be the #1 problem that developers new to OOP have. Why doesn't my object behave like a singleton? I've provided an answer since you don't seem to get it yet.

Comment: (hint: delegation is the right answer in many situations in cocoa programming)

Comment: btw: from your question's title and your variable names I do assume that you didn't fully understand MVC. I strong recommend to study it more carefully!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html

Comment: also `send.sendTo = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.recipients];` why creating a new array from another array? just do `send.sendTo = self.recipients`

Comment: Mind if I edit my code to show you the delegation I am trying? Running into a small issue.

Comment: are you asking for permission to change your question??

Comment: I'm asking if you would help me with my issue since I tried the delegation.

Comment: you are free to edit your question, I am free to help, or anybody else.

Answer (score 2):

This code creates a **brand new** instance of `SendView`...

```
SendView *send = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View"];
```

This code sets the `sendTo` property on the **brand new** instance of `SendView`.

```
send.sendTo = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.recipients];
```

At the end of the `back` method, this instance of `SendView` goes out of scope and is gone forever.

In conclusion, you must get a reference to your **existing** instance of `SendView` in order to do anything meaningful.

Comment: How do I get that reference?

Comment: and 10 points for @CrimsonChris!

Comment: Sounds confusing......

Comment: This behavior is consistent with all other object oriented languages. You should learn some OOP principals before trying to make an app. Here's a very beginner friendly tutorial tailored for iOS. http://www.raywenderlich.com/45940/intro-object-oriented-design-part-1

Comment: if you like it even more confusing you could implement a callback block.

Comment: seriously: delegation is dead simply. it is only a huge name for something trivial.